# How can i resize a SVG-image within a <h1>-Tag related to line-height?

Tags: image, css, svg

In Chrome/iOS/Firefox all seems fine, but IE10/11 doesn't align the SVG-image right in order to the Text.

I already read the http://caniuse.com/#search=svg and tried several things, but i don't get it working on IE10/11.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/re3b5ko4/3/)

```
<h1>
  <img src="http://www.kunkel-dienstleistungen.com/dev/img/logo.svg" alt="Logo">
  Kontakt
</h1>
<div>
  Text
```

```
h1 {
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.3vw;
  margin: 5vw auto 2.5vw 2vw;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
h1 > img {
  display: inline;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 2vw 0 0;
  max-height: 1em;
  width: 4vw;
}
```

You'll see a wrong alignment and wrong proportions on IE10/11.

Comment: That's because you specify a hard-coded width and a max height; causing the image to be stretched. For images to retain their h/w ratio, you can only use max-height if the width is auto, and vice versa.

Comment: ... and I don't know why it works like you expect in Firefox. Obviously I didn't expect it to work there either.

Comment: Well, if so, why iOS/Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Edge13(IE13) works like a charme?

Comment: Yes, that's the question!

Answer (score 1):

Set the `max-height` and `max-width` of the image div as below and it should work.  Tried the fiddle with ie 10 and it worked.

```
    h1 {
        font-size: 3vw;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 0.3vw;
        margin: 5vw auto 2.5vw 2vw;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    h1 > img {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0 2vw 0 0;
        max-height: 4vw;
        max-width: 4vw;
    }
```

Comment: Seems working so far, but i recently updated the JSFiddle to show you some more problem. The <h1>-Tag is globally used and has different kind of SVG-images.

Comment: On the JSFiddle yes, but not at the live-website. https://www.kunkel-dienstleistungen.com/dev/ ... See "Über uns" and "Leistungen -> Fensterreinigung"

Comment: You're right, i fixed this. Seems better now, but see "TF-Fussbodenheizungen" and "Sanitär" now, they're a bit wrong aligned!? I know, SVG seems stupid...

Comment: Hmm okay, seems to be to add a workaround here instead of some css hacks... :-/

Comment: There are probably a few hacks available :).  The only thing that I can think of is to set the header a set distance from the left margin. I updated your fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/re3b5ko4/4/  Not perfect, but it may be a good starting point.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/re3b5ko4/6/ may do the job, but the font size is a little smaller.

Comment: Yeah, i tried a similar way too, but the font-size is necessary. The problem is, that some browser interpret the "start alignment" of the SVG in a different way